# django a want show the user is login added any

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model

```
class orders5(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
      names = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

i want show the user ligin add any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logged in user can be obtain from the `request.user` attribute. So in views where you create an `orders5` object, you pass this for the `user` (there is a typo in your code, it is `user`, not <s>`uesr`</s>):

```
def some_view(request):
    # …
    orders5.objects.create(user=request.user, name='some_name')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `user` instead of <s>`users5`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `User` instead of <s>`user`</s>.